# React leaflet, the name of the place, not the coordinates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, geocoding, react-leaflet

Is it possible to render a map in React Leaflet giving the name of the place and not the map coordinates?
Instead of giving coordinates of place i wish to enter place name eg. "St. James’s Park " or "Circuit de Barcelona-Catalunya"

```
import React from "react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";

function MyMap() {
  const position = [53.35, 18.8];
  return (
    <MapContainer
      className="map"
      center={position}
      zoom={6}
      style={{ height: 500, width: "100%" }}>
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"/>
    </MapContainer>
  );
}
export default MyMap;
```

Comment: You'll need to do a geolookup for the place name first, then supply the coordinates to leaflet. You can look at [`Nominatim`](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/search.html) for example for searching the OpenStreetMap data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to apply geocoding. One solution is to use `esri-leaflet-geocoder` library.

Install it via `npm i esri-leaflet-geocoder` and create a `Geocoder` component that will take the address and will set the map view to the selected location after converting the address to coordinates.

```js
    function Geocoder({ address }) {
        const map = useMap();
    
        ELG.geocode()
          .text(address)
          .run((err, results, response) => {
            console.log(results.results[0].latlng);
            const { lat, lng } = results.results[0].latlng;
            map.setView([lat, lng], 12);
          });
    
        return null;
      }
```

Use it like this :

```
    <MapContainer
          className="map"
          center={position}
          zoom={6}
        >...
          <Geocoder address="Circuit de Barcelona-Catalunya" />
      </MapContainer>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/geocoding-in-react-leaflet-v3x-v6pm4?file=/src/MyMap.jsx:195-507)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a geolookup with the placename first like one of the comments mentioned. Here is a small example with javascript. You can implement it in React I guess. I will be using Leaflet library to draw a map using the lat and long that I will get from Nominatim query.

```
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<script>
... // getting user input
// incoming user address from input should be encoded to be used in url
const encodedAddress = encodeURIComponent(addressComingFromInput);
const nominatimURL = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?addressDetails=1&q=' + encodedAddress + '&format=json&limit=1';
// fetch lat and long and use it with leaflet
fetch(nominatimURL)
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(data => {
       const lat = data[0].lat;
       const long = data[0].lon;
       const osmTileUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
       let map = L.map('map').setView([lat, long], zoomLevel);
       L.tileLayer(osmTileUrl, {
           attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                            }).addTo(map);
      let marker = L.marker([lat, long]).addTo(map);
      marker.bindPopup(userAddress).openPopup();
   });
</script>
```